# using the verb find or finding in a setence

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to know if the sentences below are wrong? If so, why?

> Find the best talent is our job.
>   Finding the best talent is our job.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, thhconsultor. I have edited your question for idiom and formatting; before you post your next question you might consult [this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/996/32) post on our Meta section, which will help you make your question more attractive to answerers.

Answer (score 1):

Finding is a gerund (a verb with the -ing at the end). This is one way of turning a verb into a noun. So, in your sentence, 'finding' means a process or act where you find.

You can break down the sentence to its basic form. *A is our job.* We should have a noun, not a verb before *is*, so *find* doesn't fit.

Comment: You can used _find_ as a noun, though - _The_ find _was the most exciting thing to happen in decades._

Comment: @jimsug But *find*, noun, cannot take an object.

Comment: @StoneyB Certainly. I was just pointing out the difference between "finding" and "find" isn't that one of them is a noun and the other is a verb.

Answer (score 0):

The correct sentence is "Finding the best talent is our job."

"Finding" means you are doing it right now.